# Substitute single space with multiple spaces in variable

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I have a variable `text`:

```
let text="hello world"
```

and would like to put multiple spaces between the two words. How could I achieve this programmatically? This is my current solution:

```
let text=substitute(text," ","       ","")
```

but how could I put multiple spaces without typing each of them? Is there any function to put `n` number of spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `repeat()` function. From `:h repeat()`:

```
repeat({expr}, {count})                 *repeat()*
        Repeat {expr} {count} times and return the concatenated
        result.  Example: >
            :let separator = repeat('-', 80)
<       When {count} is zero or negative the result is empty.
        When {expr} is a |List| the result is {expr} concatenated
        {count} times.  Example: >
            :let longlist = repeat(['a', 'b'], 3)
<       Results in ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'].
```

For example:

```
let text = substitute(text, " ", repeat(" ", n), "")
```